# Mask a 4d tensor with a 2d mask

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor which size is (batch_size, seqLength, seqLength, label_number), and a mask tensor with size (batch_size, seqLength), when I calculate loss, I need to mask out the word that I padding in. My question is how to use this 2d mask to masking out the padding samples in the 4d tensor so that I can calculate the right loss?